# Names for X/Y coordinates of an addEventListener parameter function

Tags: javascript

In the below code `addEventListener` takes a function as parameter. My question is where can I find the documentation for the `evt.x` and `evt.y` notations.

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", getCoords);

function getCoords(evt){
    console.log(evt.x, evt.y);
    }
```

I saw in another stackoverflow question that instead of a canvas when  the window object used the `evt.x` becomes `evt.clientX` and `evt.y` becomes `evt.clientY`

```
window.addEventListener("click",function(evt){
    console.log(evt.clientX , evt.clientY );
});
```

Comment: These are properties of the `Event` object. Check the documentation of the event type.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I was looking at addEventListener documentation

Comment: And doesn't that say that the argument to the callback is an `Event`? I'll bet it's even a link.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

Comment: @Barmar It does. I'm new to JS and also new to the habit of reading documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDN Docs say that x, y are just aliases for clientX, and clientY

You can find the mdn docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event